# dynamically declaring a type to pass as parameter ...c#

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper in VS2012. Here is the signature of the autoMapper method I use:

```
         public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>();
```

It accepts two types as parameters ,mapping type #1 to type #2 and returning type #2. I have a bunch of classes that all inherit from the same source. If I try to create an AutoMap instance, I have to do the following:

```
            Mapper.CreateMap<ClassOne, ClassTwo>();  
            ClassOne one = new ClassOne{Name="One};
            ClassTwo two = Mapper.Map<ClassOne, ClassTwo>(one);
```

This will "map" all fields in ClassOne object to my ClassTwo object(yes ClassTwo has some of the fields of ClassOne). I want to setup one function that will call Mapper functions to map one object to another and not numerous functions with the same code only changing the 2 objects im mapping. I can do a GetType() on my objects and have the type I need in string format:

```
         ClassOne one = new ClassOne();
         Type t = one.GetType();
         var type = t.FullName; //type is now "Generic.Collection.ClassOne"
         Mapper.CreateMap<type, ClassTwo>();//this will not compile
         Mapper.CreateMap<one.GetType(), ClassTwo>();//neither will this
```

but I can't pass in a string to the Mapper functions. How do I declare a type dynamically?

I'm using AutoMapper as an example of how I want to declare and use a type. I have other functions that will do the same thing. So my question is how do I declare a type dynamically? - not how to use AutoMapper.

Answer (score 3):

There's another non-generic overload to the CreateMap method:

```
Mapper.CreateMap(t, typeof(ClassTwo));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using automapper wrong.

Automapper is meant to be configured at application bootstrapping, to set up a type registry of Mapper.CreateMap where T1 and T2 are types, NOT instances. You can use the string overloads to map two types together, and that'd work. The automapper registry is NOT threadsafe, so make sure you wire this up at the start of your app, *not* lazily / as you come across the types you're using.

Once you've configured automapper, just use Mapper.Map in your regular code.

Comment: AutoMapper is not the problem. My question is how do I declare a type dynamically? Not is Automapper threadsafe(thanks for the info) . I dont have to use AutoMapper at all, i just wanted to show an example of what i'm trying to accomplish